# Rails 3, using mongoid but syntax error gets produced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger, mongoid

In my development environment, which is windows 7, Ruby1.9.2p180, **everything** works fine.

However, in production environment, which is Ubuntu 10.04, Ree 1.8.7 using rvm, following error gets produced.
(I am using passenger-apache-module to run the application.)

```
/home/randomapp/public_html/app/models/article.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND field :user_id, type: Hash ^ 
/home/randomapp/public_html/app/models/article.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND field :username, type: String ^ 
/home/randomapp/public_html/app/models/article.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND field :title, type: String ^ 
/home/randomapp/public_html/app/models/article.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND field :content, type: String ^ 
/home/randomapp/public_html/app/models/article.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND field :display_content, type: String ^
```

Where those lines have below codes

```
  field :user_id, type: Hash
  field :username, type: String
  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String
  field :display_content, type: String
```

Assuming above lines work fine in development, do you think it may be a problem with syntax parser???
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using the 1.9.2 hash syntax. If you want to run on both 1.9.2 and 1.8.7 then try this:

```
field :user_id, :type => Hash
field :username, :type => String
field :title, :type => String
field :content, :type => String
field :display_content, :type => String
```